AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'replace'
I have the following code which uses TensorFlow. After I called map on my dataset list, it says
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'shape'

when I try to map elements.
Output:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[16], line 6
      3 BATCH_SIZE = 1
      5 train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('training/Minimalist_Interior/*.jpg')
----> 6 train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
      7 train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
      8 train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

.
.
.


File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileb73k_ejd.py:11, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__load_image_train(image_file)
      9 retval_ = ag__.UndefinedReturnValue()
     10 input_image = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(load), (ag__.ld(image_file),), None, fscope)
---> 11 real_image = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(load), (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(image_file).replace, ('input', 'output'), None, fscope),), None, fscope)
     12 input_image, real_image = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(random_jitter), (ag__.ld(input_image), ag__.ld(real_image)), None, fscope)
     13 input_image, real_image = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(normalize), (ag__.ld(input_image), ag__.ld(real_image)), None, fscope)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor.py:260, in Tensor.__getattr__(self, name)
    252 if name in {"T", "astype", "ravel", "transpose", "reshape", "clip", "size",
    253             "tolist", "data"}:
    254   # TODO(wangpeng): Export the enable_numpy_behavior knob
    255   raise AttributeError(
    256       f"{type(self).__name__} object has no attribute '{name}'. " + """
    257     If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
    258     tf.experimental.numpy.experimental_enable_numpy_behavior()
    259   """)
--> 260 self.__getattribute__(name)

AttributeError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\jenes\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20248\4005255074.py", line 12, in load_image_train  *
        real_image = load(image_file.replace('input', 'output'))

    AttributeError: 'SymbolicTensor' object has no attribute 'replace'

the description of the load_image_train:
def load_image_train(image_file):
    input_image = load(image_file)
    real_image = load(image_file.replace('input', 'output'))
    input_image, real_image = random_jitter(input_image, real_image)
    input_image, real_image = normalize(input_image, real_image)
    return input_image, real_image

Could anyone please tell me what I am missing?

The error you posted above and the error in the traceback are clearly not the same.

Also, please add the code for the mapping function (load_image_train) to the question.

@mhenning I added the code for the mapping function
